# Chrome err_blocked_by_client

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, safari

My app opens in iframe on the third-party website. I need to get a URL string from host-window's HTMLELement which I have an access to and open this URL in a new tab.

I tried this:

```
window.open(linkToOpen, "_blank");
```

... and this:

```
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.style.display = "none";
a.href = linkToOpen;
a.download = "file.pdf";
a.target = "_blank";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
a.remove();
```

In Mozilla everythig works fine, but Chrome blocks redirect with error ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT and Safari opens a blank page. Usual links (e.g. "https:// domain.com/path") are opened fine in Chrome and Safari, but not the link which leads to the file (e.g. "https:// domain.com/path/to/invoice.pdf").

Also there is no Adblocker.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to any plugin installed in chrome, I recommend you to turn off all plugins and try again.

Comment: there are no plugins at all. Also tried incognito mode - same problem. Links work, but links to files don't.